# filtered results with s3cmd get

Tags: regex, amazon-s3, get, s3cmd, buckets

I'm using cmd tool for AWS S3 called s3cmd. I'm trying 'get' set of folders filtered by front part of name directory name like '/192.168.*/'. Basically I have S3 bucket with a lot of directories and I just need couple of them that start with particular string. Here is what I have so far. Will be grateful for any kind of help :) Thank you!

```
s3cmd get --recursive --include '192.168*' s3://mys3bucket/logfiles/
```

Code above pulls down all the directories from /logfiles/. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s3cmd get --recursive s3://mys3bucket/logfiles/192.168
```

Comment: That is the first thing I tried but 's3cmd' can't accept '/192.168*'

Comment: this command won't produce any output, I believe i goto use '--exclude/--include' but can't figure out how to use them with 'get'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "filter" for files that match a certain name, you can do this:

```bash
s3cmd get --recursive --exclude '*' --include 'filename*' s3://my-bucket/cheese
```